# My Shopify's config.webhook settings enqueued ActiveJob properly but I didn't get to have it save the record details in the db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, webhooks, shopify-app, ruby-on-rails-6

### *Issues*: OrderPaidJob is not saving into the database.

**OrderPaidJob**

```
class OrdersPaidJob < ApplicationJob

  def perform(shop_domain:, webhook:)
    shop = Shop.find_by(shopify_domain: shop_domain)

    shop.with_shopify_session do
      webhook.each(&method(:customer_details))
    end
  end

  private

  def customer_details(record)
    payload = {
      email: record['email'],
      amount_spent: record['total_price'].to_f,
      first_name: record['customer']['first_name'],
      last_name: record['customer']['last_name'],
      point_balance: (EarningRule.order_rule.point * record['total_price'].to_f) + previous_point(record)
    }

    records = [].tap do |array|
      array << payload
    end

    customer_exists(record) ? CustomerDetail.update_all(records) : CustomerDetail.insert_all(records)
  end

  def previous_point(record)
    return 0 unless customer_exists(record)

    customer_exists(record).point_balance
  end

  def customer_exists(record)
    CustomerDetail.find_by_email(record[:email])
  end
end
```

**Shopify_app.rb**

```
ShopifyApp.configure do |config|
  config.application_name = 'Loyalty'
  config.api_key = ENV['SHOPIFY_API_KEY']
  config.secret = ENV['SHOPIFY_API_SECRET']
  config.old_secret = ''
  config.scope = 'read_orders'
  config.embedded_app = true
  config.after_authenticate_job = false
  config.api_version = '2019-10'
  config.session_repository = Shop
  config.webhooks = [
    {
      topic: 'orders/paid',
      address: 'https://6c62d547.ngrok.io/webhooks/orders_paid', fields: %w[email total_price customer],
      format: 'json'
    }
  ]
end
```

*route.rb*

```
I don't have anything in route
```

**Log**

```
I, [2019-11-18T00:41:37.361206 #8576]  INFO -- : [49b5712f-fb92-448e-9ef8-34a121040843] Started POST "/webhooks/orders_paid" for 104.196.45.139 at 2019-11-18 00:41:37 +0100
I, [2019-11-18T00:41:37.371934 #8576]  INFO -- : [49b5712f-fb92-448e-9ef8-34a121040843] Processing by ShopifyApp::WebhooksController#receive as */*
I, [2019-11-18T00:41:37.372121 #8576]  INFO -- : [49b5712f-fb92-448e-9ef8-34a121040843]   Parameters: {"email"=>"tam@tam.com", "total_price"=>"42000.00", "customer"=>{"id"=>2730242670669, "email"=>"tam@tam.com", "accepts_marketing"=>true, "created_at"=>"2019-11-15T10:21:15+01:00", "updated_at"=>"2019-11-18T00:41:24+01:00", "first_name"=>"Olaoluwa", "last_name"=>"Afolabi", "orders_count"=>8, "state"=>"disabled", "total_spent"=>"378000.00", "last_order_id"=>1869178699853, "note"=>"Something", "verified_email"=>true, "multipass_identifier"=>nil, "tax_exempt"=>false, "phone"=>"+2348032", "tags"=>"Tester", "last_order_name"=>"#1010", "currency"=>"NGN", "accepts_marketing_updated_at"=>"2019-11-15T10:21:15+01:00", "marketing_opt_in_level"=>"single_opt_in", "admin_graphql_api_id"=>"gid://shopify/Customer/2730242670669", "default_address"=>{"id"=>2886602129485, "customer_id"=>2730242670669, "first_name"=>"Olaoluwa", "last_name"=>"Afolabi", "company"=>"Quidax", "address1"=>"No 4B, George Street", "address2"=>"Something", "city"=>"Ikoyi, Lagos", "province"=>"Lagos", "country"=>"Nigeria", "zip"=>"250001", "phone"=>"+2348032", "name"=>"Olaoluwa Afolabi", "province_code"=>"LA", "country_code"=>"NG", "country_name"=>"Nigeria", "default"=>true}}, "type"=>"orders_paid", "webhook"=>{"email"=>"tam@tam.com", "total_price"=>"42000.00", "customer"=>{"id"=>2730242670669, "email"=>"tam@tam.com", "accepts_marketing"=>true, "created_at"=>"2019-11-15T10:21:15+01:00", "updated_at"=>"2019-11-18T00:41:24+01:00", "first_name"=>"Olaoluwa", "last_name"=>"Afolabi", "orders_count"=>8, "state"=>"disabled", "total_spent"=>"378000.00", "last_order_id"=>1869178699853, "note"=>"Something", "verified_email"=>true, "multipass_identifier"=>nil, "tax_exempt"=>false, "phone"=>"+2348682", "tags"=>"Tester", "last_order_name"=>"#1010", "currency"=>"NGN", "accepts_marketing_updated_at"=>"2019-11-15T10:21:15+01:00", "marketing_opt_in_level"=>"single_opt_in", "admin_graphql_api_id"=>"gid://shopify/Customer/2730242670669", "default_address"=>{"id"=>2886602129485, "customer_id"=>2730242670669, "first_name"=>"Olaoluwa", "last_name"=>"Afolabi", "company"=>"Quidax", "address1"=>"No 4B, George Street", "address2"=>"Something", "city"=>"Ikoyi, Lagos", "province"=>"Lagos", "country"=>"Nigeria", "zip"=>"250001", "phone"=>"+234803382", "name"=>"Olaoluwa Afolabi", "province_code"=>"LA", "country_code"=>"NG", "country_name"=>"Nigeria", "default"=>true}}}}
I, [2019-11-18T00:41:37.587617 #8576]  INFO -- : [49b5712f-fb92-448e-9ef8-34a121040843] [ActiveJob] Enqueued OrdersPaidJob (Job ID: 953e3ef2-66d8-4422-8de6-75abef4b55e8) to Sidekiq(default) with arguments: {:shop_domain=>"shopsloyalty.myshopify.com", :webhook=>{"email"=>"tam@tam.com", "total_price"=>"42000.00", "customer"=>{"id"=>2730242670669, "email"=>"tam@tam.com", "accepts_marketing"=>true, "created_at"=>"2019-11-15T10:21:15+01:00", "updated_at"=>"2019-11-18T00:41:24+01:00", "first_name"=>"Olaoluwa", "last_name"=>"Afolabi", "orders_count"=>8, "state"=>"disabled", "total_spent"=>"378000.00", "last_order_id"=>1869178699853, "note"=>"Something", "verified_email"=>true, "multipass_identifier"=>nil, "tax_exempt"=>false, "phone"=>"+2348715682", "tags"=>"Tester", "last_order_name"=>"#1010", "currency"=>"NGN", "accepts_marketing_updated_at"=>"2019-11-15T10:21:15+01:00", "marketing_opt_in_level"=>"single_opt_in", "admin_graphql_api_id"=>"gid://shopify/Customer/2730242670669", "default_address"=>{"id"=>2886602129485, "customer_id"=>2730242670669, "first_name"=>"Olaoluwa", "last_name"=>"Afolabi", "company"=>"Quidax", "address1"=>"No 4B, George Street", "address2"=>"Something", "city"=>"Ikoyi, Lagos", "province"=>"Lagos", "country"=>"Nigeria", "zip"=>"250001", "phone"=>"+234805682", "name"=>"Olaoluwa Afolabi", "province_code"=>"LA", "country_code"=>"NG", "country_name"=>"Nigeria", "default"=>true}}, "webhook"=>{"email"=>"tam@tam.com", "total_price"=>"42000.00", "customer"=>{"id"=>2730242670669, "email"=>"tam@tam.com", "accepts_marketing"=>true, "created_at"=>"2019-11-15T10:21:15+01:00", "updated_at"=>"2019-11-18T00:41:24+01:00", "first_name"=>"Olaoluwa", "last_name"=>"Afolabi", "orders_count"=>8, "state"=>"disabled", "total_spent"=>"378000.00", "last_order_id"=>1869178699853, "note"=>"Something", "verified_email"=>true, "multipass_identifier"=>nil, "tax_exempt"=>false, "phone"=>"+234803682", "tags"=>"Tester", "last_order_name"=>"#1010", "currency"=>"NGN", "accepts_marketing_updated_at"=>"2019-11-15T10:21:15+01:00", "marketing_opt_in_level"=>"single_opt_in", "admin_graphql_api_id"=>"gid://shopify/Customer/2730242670669", "default_address"=>{"id"=>2886602129485, "customer_id"=>2730242670669, "first_name"=>"Olaoluwa", "last_name"=>"Afolabi", "company"=>"Quidax", "address1"=>"No 4B, George Street", "address2"=>"Something", "city"=>"Ikoyi, Lagos", "province"=>"Lagos", "country"=>"Nigeria", "zip"=>"250001", "phone"=>"+23480382", "name"=>"Olaoluwa Afolabi", "province_code"=>"LA", "country_code"=>"NG", "country_name"=>"Nigeria", "default"=>true}}}}}
I, [2019-11-18T00:41:37.588710 #8576]  INFO -- : [49b5712f-fb92-448e-9ef8-34a121040843] Completed 204 No Content in 216ms (Allocations: 2512)
```

Can someone help me? I don’t know what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

You probably missed the step of actually running your job. Just because the Shopify App enqueued it for you, does not mean you ran the job. Depending on your choice of job runner, you need to set that up. So a worker to run DelayedJob or Sidekiq or whatever you chose. That is where you probably want to examine your setup. What is your Procfile? A dead giveaway is missing the worker entry.

Comment: No actually. The job is okay. I have fixed it. I was just not picking the right attributes from the payload returned to save in the DB. That is why. It works now. The problem is with the `webhook.each`

Comment: Oh, my apologies. I really appreciate your post and I am sorry not to have mentioned THANK YOU. Thanks so much. I didn't slap. Or did I mistakenly click something? Let me check. I am on mobile on the go.

Comment: Oh I am really sorry David. That was a mistake. I didn't even know. I have made corrections to that. Should reflect after editing. My apologies.